# IE9 and Flash z-index problem

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, css

I saw some other post similar to this topic, but couldn't find the sollution, maybe someone knows...

I have swf object with z-index:-5; position:absolute;  also a div with ul in it where div has also, z-inde:5; position:absolute;

All browsers display div over my flash except IE9.

Can some tell me about the sollution?

Comment: Are your wmodes set to transparent, both in the embed and object tags?

Comment: Can you show us how you're embedding the flash movie into your webpage?

Comment: the thing is that i'm not directly setting object into HTML.. i'm using Javascript because it's xml kinda Flash Slider... so I have wmode to transparent.. then somewhere I saw that wmode opaque could help - but it didn't

Answer (score 12):

Try putting this param into your embed video:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
             <embed runat="server" id="embedLnk" style="z-index:0;" src="" 
             type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
             allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque"
             allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="190">
             </embed>
```

Comment: Pushed the third party overlay up to the top so the close tab was available. Worked fine in every browser except IE8-9 and adding `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` fixed it up like a charm in the terrible IEs!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, and I didn't even need to set the z-index of the Flash, just of the DIV I wanted to overlay.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, declare the background color on the overlay div, along with an opacity of 0. (It won't matter what color you choose, because you're making it transparent.)

Answer (score -1):

Have you taken a look at [this site](http://www.davidtong.me/z-index-misconceptions-bugs-fixes/)?  It talks about z-index stacking and how it sometimes doesn't work intuitively.  IE (surprise surprise) seems to handle things differently than others.

I thought I also once read that all content displayed via a plug-in gets rendered on top of all other content regardless of z-index, but I've also read that there are workarounds (see [this](http://www.leosquarez.com/embed-videoflash-z-index-issue/)) - but it doesn't sound like that's your issue.